# Neo4J path planning and properties

Tags: routes, neo4j

I want to find the cheapest path through my graph based on a cost property.
But I also want to exclude certain relations based on a second properties.

Think of a building with rooms and you can only pass through certain doors if you fit the door.

My relations are defines as:

```
Door {cost: Number, height: Number}
```

With the rest API I am completely fine using the Dijkstra algorithm to traverse the rooms using the cost property. But I did not find a way how to include the condition on the door height.

- Is there a way to include this extra constraint in the Rest API?
  Cypher is more flexible here but does not allow to use Dijkstra currently...
- In a later implementation I want to switch to use A-Star as my planning algorithm. I want to solve this with a plugin. Do I then have to implement my custom `PathExpander` or is there a way to use the traversal functions? From what I have understood traversal can only be user with depth and breadth first search.

Comment: How are you doing Dijkstra's here?  In cypher, it's easy enough to query for paths that have the condition on height.   I.e. `MATCH (p)-[:door*1..10]->(q) WHERE door.height > 5` but that's not doing Dijkstra's in the query.

Comment: Dijkstra would be used via the Rest API (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-and-get-a-single-path) cypher would not be efficient enough.

Comment: I think going with a server extension is currently the way to go. Then you are most flexible with your expansion, cost calculation and filtering.

Comment: I managed to implement this already, thanks! BTW: Any idea why property filtering is not an option in the current implementations of the Graph Algorithms? It seems such an obvious feature?!